# Split html between two divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two divs. Both are 400 px height. User enters text in WYSIWYG editor. 
I need to split this HTML text in a way that div #1 is filled first and when it's full (no more text will fit) I need to start appending to another div.

It it was plain text I would split it on newlines and then line by line I would copy to `div #1` and, when it's full, to `#div 2`.
But since it's HTML I don't know how to split it.

I cannot use CSS columns because I need different styles for each column.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I have no idea what should I try.

Comment: @Tom You are looking for CSS Columns.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I can't use CSS Columns. My divs are not next to each other.

Comment: @Tom Can you make it into one `div` and use? Check the below snippet. It is better than calculating based on resolution, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is CSS Columns. Check the interactive example:

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function () {
    $("#columns").append('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore facere hic enim debitis, aspernatur minima voluptas maxime nemo eos aliquam sint tempora quidem cum ipsum, suscipit neque praesentium culpa repellat.<br /><br />');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#columns {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

#columns:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<a href="#">Add Text</a>
<div id="columns"></div>
```

**Advantages:**

- Responsive widths.
- No need for calculating correct cut-off position.

**Disadvantages:**

- Single `<div>`.
- Modern Browsers needed.

Comment: Can I give different styles to each column? For example make the second column red or absolutely positioned?

Comment: @Tom I am not sure.. But will check the possibility for you.

Comment: @Tom Sorry, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: @tom yes you can change the colour of second column by using the ::before selector. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xxux1e57/)

Comment: @Tom Added the colours as you asked. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Since I have nothing else anyway I accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want news paper kind of layout you can simply use column-count css property

```css
.parent-div{
  column-count:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
</div>
```